Recent Bioinformatics Graduate Seeking Resources for NGS and Drug Discovery
I recently graduated with a bachelor's degree in bioinformatics. Unfortunately, the bioinformatics program at my university was limited, and I'm feeling the need to expand my knowledge in specific areas.
I'm particularly interested in next-generation sequencing (NGS) and  drug discovery.  I'd greatly appreciate any recommendations for resources that could help me gain a deeper understanding of these topics.
Specifically, I'm looking for:
Books: Introductory or intermediate-level texts that cover NGS technologies, data analysis, and applications in drug discovery.
Online Courses: Structured courses or tutorials that provide practical training in NGS analysis and its use in drug development pipelines.

I'm closing this question because it is of a general/discussion nature, and not related to a specific bioinformatics problem. Please ask discussion-type questions on discussion-based communities, like reddit.

@gringer I believe that reference request questions are not   general/discussion nature

For specific requests, yes, we have allowed it in the past (e.g. here). If you want to change to a specific topic, please do that, but I'm seeing 1) books on NGS technologies; 2) books on data analysis; 3) books on NGS use in drug discovery; 4) courses for NGS analysis; 5) courses for NGS use in drug discovery. It's better to ask multiple questions than to create a single post with multiple subquestions/areas. However, I expect you'll get a better response elsewhere with these requests.
